# AJAX get запрос к серверу

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Добрый вечер всем. Только приступил к изучению AJAX, в php и mysql тоже новичок.
Создал БД и таблицу users с полями id, name, email. 
Скрипт для подключения к бд выглядит так

```
<?php 
    $dblocation = "localhost";
    $dbname = "test5";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpasswd = "";

$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dblocation, $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
if (!$dbcnx) {
    exit ( "<p>В настоящий момент сервер базы данных недоступен, поэтому корректное отображение страницы невозможно.</p>" );
}

if ( ! @mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbcnx)) {
    exit ( "<p>В настоящий момент база данных недоступна, поэтому корректное отображение страницы невозможно.</p>" );
}
?>
```

код странички, с которой отправляет запрос (в поле ввода вбивается id пользователя и из бд выводится информация по этому пользователю)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Главная страница</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#button-1').on('click', function () {
                    var id = $('#user-id').val();
                    $.trim(id);
                    var regexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
                    if (regexp.test(id) && id > 0)
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: 'get-user.php',
                            datatype: "html",
                            data: {
                                'id': id
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                showMessage(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        showMessage('Неправильное значение');
                    }
                });

                function showMessage(data)
                {
                    $('#info').html(data);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Главная страница</h2>
        <input name="id" id="user-id" type="text" size="15" />
        <button id="button-1">Получить данные</button>
        <div id="info"></div>
</html>
```

собственно, сам скрипт, который возвращает значения

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if ( $id == '' )
    {
        unset($id);
    }

    if (empty($id))
    {
        $info = "Пустое значение id";
    }
    else 
    {       
        $id = stripslashes ($id);
        $id = htmlspecialchars ($id);
        $id = trim($id);
        //intval($id);

        if(is_numeric($id) && is_int($id) && $id > 0)
        {
            include ("db.php"); 
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE id='$id'", $dbcnx);
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            if(!empty($row))
            {
                $info = "Имя пользователя: ".$row[0]."<br/>Email: ".$row[1];
            }
            else
            {
                $info = "В базе нет пользователя с таким id";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $info = "Вы ввели не числовое, не целочисленное или отрицательное значение id";
        }
    }
    echo $info;
}
```

?>

Два вопроса:
 1. Не работает проверочное условие `if(is_numeric($id) && is_int($id) && $id > 0)`, точнее говоря в нем не работает проверка `is_int($id)` и если я ввожу ид, которого заведомо нет в таблице, например, 56, то получаю не `В базе нет пользователя с таким id` , а `Вы ввели не числовое, не целочисленное или отрицательное значение id`
 Не могу понять, почему эта проверка не работает, даже если я перед условием делаю приведение к целочисленному типу `intval($id);`
 2. Второй вопрос: правильно ли я делаю что добавляю так много разных проверок введенного значения и на клиентской и на серверной стороне? Или наоборот надо добавить какие-то еще проверки?

**UPD** В комментах подсказали, переписал условие вот так `if(is_numeric($id) && ((int)$id == $id) && (int)$id > 0)`, вроде заработало, так что первый вопрос снимается.
Про проверки расскажите, плиз, все ли нужны или еще что-то добавить надо?

Comment: trim возвращает строку, а строка не int (капитан, да)

Comment: но проверку `is_numeric($id)` оно проходит, и я же говорю, даже если делаю приведение типа `intval($id);` перед условием все равно условие не работает.

Comment: Возвращает TRUE, если var является числом или числовой строкой, FALSE - в ином случае.

Comment: аа, понял, переписал условие вот так `if(is_numeric($id) && ((int)$id == $id) && (int)$id > 0)`, вроде заработало

Comment: а смысл проверки (int)$id == $id? почему бы не работать с приведенным значением?

Comment: Проверки лишними никогда не бывают, особенно если проверяете данные, введенные (или которые могут быть введены) пользователем.

Comment: @mazanax что-то не совсем понимаю, как?

Comment: вы привели $id к (int), следовательно, все лишнее отсеялось и теперь можно это пихать в запрос

Comment: возможно меня назовут быдлокодером, но почему бы не сделать так:
$id=intval($id); if($id>0){//тут код}

Comment: @mazanax остается проблема, если в $id была возможность передать 0 или отрицательные числа. Так просто уже не определить. Да и запись `intval('3d');` будет тройкой, на сколько это подходит неизвестно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На счет проверок, мои мысли:

> Всему есть предел, делая избыточно много проверок вы сами захлебнетесь в бессмысленной писанине. Каждая проверка должна быть осмысленной.

```
// Да, замечательная проверка, не существует переменной, нечего соваться
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    // Если вы ниже ожидаете число, переводите сразу в число
    // $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // Если нужно, можете проверить преобразованное число с тем что было, 
    // и при не совпадении отказаться выполнять дальше

    // У вас же число? при intval это будет = 0
    // Кстати, empty('') вернет true, 
    // зачем с начала создавать переменную потом в следующей строке удалять ее?
    if ( $id == '' )
    {
        unset($id);
    }

    // Что вы тут добивались?
    if (empty($id))
    {
        $info = "Пустое значение id";
    }
    else 
    {       
        // Все замечательно, но если вы ожидаете число, зачем вам экранировать символы?
        $id = stripslashes ($id);
        $id = htmlspecialchars ($id);
        $id = trim($id);
        //intval($id);

        // Вы просто делаете бессмысленные операции
        // Мало того что по 10 раз переводите $id в (int), 
        // при такой реализации в одном месте можно забыть перевести в (int) и проскочит ошибка
        // Как уже сказал лучше сразу из $_GET и $_POST запросов сразу обработать параметры как надо и дальше доверять полученным переменным, как будто они родные.
        if (is_numeric($id) && ((int)$id == $id) && (int)$id > 0)
        //if(is_numeric($id) && is_int($id) && $id > 0)
        {
            include ("db.php"); 
            // Вот отсюда могла пойти ошибка (простым копи-пастом или удалением некоторых условий). Повсюду переводите в число, а вот в самом ответственном месте вставляете как есть, заметьте, $id равен чистому $_GET['id']
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE id='$id'", $dbcnx);
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            if(!empty($row))
            {
                $info = "Имя пользователя: ".$row[0]."<br/>Email: ".$row[1];
            }
            else
            {
                $info = "В базе нет пользователя с таким id";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            // А еще это может быть 0
            $info = "Вы ввели не числовое, не целочисленное или отрицательное значение id";
        }
    }
    echo $info;
}
```

Надеюсь свою мысль сумел донести :)

Comment: @IVsevolod большое спасибо за ответ, поразбираюсь! а что за "готовые решения" вы имели в виду в комментарии выше?

Comment: @ims к примеру в Yii фреймворке есть такой конструктор запросов:

    $user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
     ->select('id, username, profile')
     ->from('tbl_user u')
     ->join('tbl_profile p', 'u.id=p.user_id')
     ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
     ->queryRow();

Тут он сам будет экранировать и обрабатывать $id. Будет бороться с инъекциями и т.д. )

Comment: а какие за фреймворки можете посоветовать?

Comment: @ims К сожалению я только этим фреймворком пользовался. Но на хешкоде есть вопросы на эту тему, можете поискать и почитать, кто что пишет )

Comment: @IVsevolod спасибо, почитаю. а про Yii что можете сказать, как ваши впечатления?

Comment: @ims Концепция MVC вполне так поддерживается, и даже можно hmvc сделать ). Создавать просто, поддерживать просто. Много готовых плюшек, которые облегчают разработку.

Comment: @IVsevolod ага, понятненько, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $id = stripslashes ($id);
    $id = htmlspecialchars ($id);
    $id = trim($id);
    //intval($id);

    if(is_numeric($id) && is_int($id) && $id > 0)
```

Рукалицо просто.

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

И всё! Там сразу будет либо цифра, либо 0, если там пусто.

Comment: ну может я конечно и не прав, но так как я новичок, то сейчас читаю мануалы и учебники и там написано,что для обработки введенных данных надо использовать сначала функции htmlspecialchars(), trim() и stripslashes(), а потом уже производить над данными какие-то манипуляции.

Comment: > $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

Вот с этим согласен - если вы ожидаете от входных параметров число, то преобразуйте его сразу в число, чтобы потом не думать "а не число ли это". Ну, можно рядом еще проверить это действительно было число.


Со строками (особенно которые идут в запрос к БД) надо отдельно работать, экранировать и все дела. Вообще, по хорошему работать с готовыми решениями, и самому особо не думать, но для развития полезно знать "что и почему".

Comment: @IVsevolod то есть, сделать проверку `is_numeric($id)` , приведение ` $id = (int)$_GET['id'];` ?  

а что означает  

"Вообще, по хорошему работать с готовыми решениями, и самому особо не думать, но для развития полезно знать "что и почему". " ?

Comment: @ims Например использовать фреймворки. Я имел в виду использовать конструкторы запросов, т.е. все запросы не в чистом виде формируются и проверка на инъекции не на вас лежит (но вам, в принципе, тоже надо задумываться об этом).